# How to close a UIFrame window from the object itself? (Behavioral difference GMS 1.x to GMS 2.x)

Tags: dm-script

In GMS2.x, closing UIFrame window with the code shown below will cause DM to crash (at pressing the *close* button.)

However, the same code works fine with GMS 1.x.

Is there a way to work around this problem in GMS 2.x?

```
class UIWindowCloseTest : UIFrame {

    void CloseSelf( object self ) self.GetFrameWindow().WindowClose(0);

    UIWindowCloseTest( object self ) {
        TagGroup tgDialog = DLGCreateDialog( "window close test" );
        tgDialog.DLGAddElement( DLGCreatePushButton( "Close", "CloseSelf" ));
        self.super.init(tgDialog);
        self.Display( "test" );
        result( self.ScriptObjectGetID().Hex() + " constructed\n" );
    };

    ~UIWindowCloseTest( object self ) \
        result( self.ScriptObjectGetID().Hex() + " destructed\n\n" );
};

alloc(UIWindowCloseTest);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### This is the extension of this questions for GMS 3.X:

In essense, the [answer below](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28095034/1302888) is correct for GMS 3 as well, but only since its version 3.2 (Maybe GMS 3.1.2 as well).

Earlier versions of GMS 3 have a bug as KEVIVI pointed out in the comment to the answer.

However, there is a work-around solution to this, which is slightly elaborate:

```
Class myDLG : UIframe
{
    myDLG(object self)  result("\n Create DLG")
    ~myDLG(object self) result("\n Kill DLG")

    void DeferredClose( object self )
    {
        TagGroup tgs = GetPersistentTagGroup()
        number scriptID
        if ( tgs.TagGroupGetTagAsLong( "DummyTag_CloseWindow_ID", scriptID ) )
        {
            object obj = GetScriptObjectFromID( scriptID )
            if ( obj.ScriptObjectIsValid() )
            {
                obj.GetFrameWindow().WindowClose(0)
                return
            }
        }
        Debug( "\n Sorry, but could not close dialog." )
    }

    void CloseButtonAction( object self )    
    {
        // Normally, it would be save to use "self.close()" here,
        // but due to a bug, this is currenlty not possible in GMS 3.1
        // The alternative method of getting the window of the UIframe object
        // and closing it, is okay, but it must not be called directly here,
        // or it will crash DM.
        // As a work-around, one can store the object ID and have a separate
        // thread pick it up, get the object, and close the object's window.
        // This is, what we are doing below.


        // Write ScriptID into tags 
        TagGroup tgs = GetPersistentTagGroup()
        tgs.TagGroupSetTagAsLong( "DummyTag_CloseWindow_ID", self.ScriptObjectGetID() ) 

        // Launch separate thread just to close... (0.1 sec delay for safety)
        AddMainThreadSingleTask( self, "DeferredClose", 0.1 )
    }

    TagGroup CreateDLG(object self)
    {
        TagGroup DLGtg,DLGtgItems
        DLGtg=DLGCreateDialog("my Dialog",DLGtgItems)
        DLGtgItems.DLGAddElement(DLGCreatePushButton("Close","CloseButtonAction"))
        return DLGtg
    }
}

{
    object dialog=Alloc(myDLG)
    dialog.Init( dialog.CreateDLG() )
    dialog.display("")
}
```

---

So:

- For GMS 3.2 and later: Use `self.close();`
- For GMS 3.0 and 3.1 (with the bug): Use the workaround.
- For GMS 2.x: Use `self.close();`
- For GMS 1.x: Use `self.GetFrameWindow().WindowClose(0);`

Answer (score 1):

Yes,
in GMS 2.x you have to use

`self.close();`

instead of

`self.GetFrameWindow().WindowClose(0);`

Comment: How about in GMS 3.x? 

self.close();

no longer close UIFrame in GMS 3.x and no error message is thrown..

Comment: @KEVIVI GMS 3.0 has a bug which is fixed in the latest GMS 3.1 release already. It is possible to work around this issue with a slightly elaborate idea: Create a separate thread just to close your window. I can post it as an example here in a moment....