# DM script to close dialog window

Tags: user-interface, dm-script

I am looking for a proper way to close a UI window. 
The following code works for GMS 1.x.

```
Class mainUI:uiframe {
  void CloseMe(object self){
    DocumentWindow win=self.GetFrameWindow();
    if(win.WindowIsValid()) win.WindowClose(0);
  }
}
```

But this code crashes DigitalMicrograph consistently under GMS 2.33.

Comment: The key is to use the new Close method of UIFrame in GMS 2.3.  This question is covered in one of the auxiliary answers provided in the following post from February 2015: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28776137/closing-a-modal-dialog-in-gms-2-x-and-gms-1-x

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Mike pointed out in the comment: The answer is to use `dlg.Close()` where *dlg* would be your dialog object.

Here is an example for GMS 3.2. ( See also [this for GMS 3.1](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41955633/1302888) )

```
class myDlg : UIframe
{
    void OnClose( object self )
    {
        self.Close()
    }

    object InitAndLaunch( object self )
    {
        TagGroup dlg, dlgItems
        dlg = DLGCreateDialog( "test", dlgItems )
        dlgItems.DLGAddElement( DLGCreatePushButton( "Close", "OnClose" ) )
        self.Init(dlg)
        self.Display( "Test" )
        return self
    }
}

Alloc(myDLG).InitAndLaunch()
```

Comment: Great,  `self.close()` inside class `UI:UIFrame` works for GMS 2.3. But does not work for GMS 3.1. Is there a different solution for GMS 3?

Comment: @user6406828 I've added an exmaple which I've just now tested OK on GMS 3.2.2. Does this not run on your system? The error you see might not be in the command, but in your dialog-script. Potentially post a slimmed down version of your problematic code. (i.e. edit your question)

Comment: No. The above script won't close the dlg on GMS 3.10 (free version). No error message. Just no action when click "Close".

Comment: Sorry that I missed your "workaround" method here, [link] (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28091599/how-to-close-a-uiframe-window-from-the-object-itself-behavioral-difference-gms?rq=1). That works. The problem should be the bug with GMS 3.1.

Comment: @user6406828 Maybe obvious, but if you're running the free version of GMS 3.1 I would recommend that you rather update to the (also free) latest GMS version (3.2.2 at the moment).